# Jmeter - Stop reading CSV file after find out right item

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have a CSV file like:

> brandid1,brandurl1,producturl1
>
> brandid2,brandurl2,producturl2
>
> brandid3,brandurl3,producturl3

and a variable ${brandid} that get from previously response. **Now i  want to find a brandurl and producturl from CSV file if brandid are same (ex: ${brandid} == ${brandid2}, it will return brandurl2 and producturl2) Them script will stop without run whole csv file.**

I have to use "While" controller and BSF Preprocessor but the script always run whole csv file.

> While ("${tmp}"=="1")
>
> --http request (use brandurl,producturl)
>
> --csv file
>
> --HTTP Header Manager
>
> --BSF PreProcessor

With tmp declare in global `tmp=1` and BSF as below:

```
  var brand_idOfWH = vars.get("brand_idOfWH");
var brandid_csv = vars.get("brandid");

 var brandurl = vars.get("brandurl");
 vars.put("brand_url",brandurl);
 
 var producturl = vars.get("producturl");
 vars.put("product_url",producturl);
 
if (brand_idOfWH == brandid_csv)
{
 vars.put("tmp","0");
}
```

Please help me to stop reading CSV file if i find out right `brandid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are misusing While Controller, as per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) it accepts either **function** or **variable**, it cannot parse your expression hence it won't exit the loop. The correct function will look something like:

   ```
   ${__javaScript("${tmp}" == "1",)}
   ```
2. It isn't very recommended to use BSF test elements for scripting. If you ever have to overcome a JMeter limitation via scripting consider using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and "groovy" as a language - this way you'll get optimal performance. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for detailed instructions on installing Groovy scripting engine support and Groovy scripting best practices.