# Jmeter - HTTP request run one time when find out right result

Tags: csv, jmeter

After i pass issue by modify condition in "while" in [Jmeter - Stop reading CSV file after find out right item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063975/jmeter-stop-reading-csv-file-after-find-out-right-item/32065036#32065036)

Now i want to run "http request" one time only when i find out right product. Currently, number of "http request" is equal number of loop in while.

How can i run HTTP request one time?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understand your question correctly but would not https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller help?

It is triggered only once per each thread. Usually used for logins.

Comment: thank for your response, but this is not answer that i need. Could you see my test plan in < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063975/jmeter-stop-reading-csv-file-after-find-out-right-item/32065036#32065036 > and my expected in this page.

Answer (score 0):

I used "IF controller" in "While Controller" and resolve this issue.

> While ("${Error}"=="Response Error")
>
> CSV file (brandid,brandurl,producturl)
>
> if ("${brandOfWH}"=="${brandid}")
>
> -- Http request
>
> -- -- BSF Preprocessor
>
> -- -- Get "Error" extractor